# Has anyone identified issues when using Blue Prism version 6.2?

Tags: virtual-machine, rpa, blueprism

I am attempting to begin building an automation sequence for a client however they are only able to use Blueprism version 6.2 right now. Does anyone know of installing, coding, scheduling, or running issues with this version? Can you also link where the issue has been discussed/resolved?

Comment: This question is unfortunately not specific enough for Stack Overflow's Q&A format. (See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Comment: More directly to the question, Blue Prism includes Known Issues in each version's Release Notes, available on the Blue Prism portal.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure they are using the latest patch level for 6.2 (which is 6.2.2) in order to ensure they do not experience issues around scheduling. Details will be available in the Release Notes for 6.2.2 on the Blue Prism portal.